# Root node always becoming NULL when traversing

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

In this binary tree implementation
I've tried to create an object from the `BinaryTree` class and thus insert elements and access them in order. While debugging it seems it's always returning root as NULL and thus the traversal fails.

I don't understand what I'm missing here. Where is my mistake?

```
public class BinaryTree{
    public static class Node{
        int value;
        Node left;
        Node right;
        public Node(int data){
            this.value = data;
            left = null;
            right = null;
        }
    }
    
    Node root;
    BinaryTree() { 
        root = null; 
    }
    
    public Node addrecursive(Node current,int value){
        if(current==null){
            return new Node(value);
        }else
        if(value<current.value){
            int n=current.value;
            current.left=addrecursive(current.left,value);
        }else
        if(value>current.value){
            int n=current.value;
            current.right=addrecursive(current.right,value);
        }else
        {
            return current;
        }
        return current;
    }

    public void add(int value) {
        Node n = null; 
        if(root==null) 
            root = addrecursive(root, value);
        else
            n = addrecursive(n, value);
    }

    private void createBinaryTree(){
        BinaryTree bt = new BinaryTree();
        bt.add(6);
        bt.add(4);
        bt.add(8);
        bt.add(3);
        bt.add(5);
        bt.add(7);
        bt.add(9);
        return;
    }

    private boolean containsNodeRecursive(Node current, int value) {
        if (current == null) {
            return false;
        } 
        if (value == current.value) {
            return true;
        } 
        return value < current.value
          ? containsNodeRecursive(current.left, value)
          : containsNodeRecursive(current.right, value);
    }

    public boolean containsNode(int value) {
        return containsNodeRecursive(this.root, value);
    }

    public void traverseInOrder(Node node) {
        if (node != null) {
            traverseInOrder(node.left);
            System.out.print(" " + node.value);
            traverseInOrder(node.right);
        }
    }
    void printInorder() {              //wrapper class for access without passing node
        traverseInOrder(root); 
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        BinaryTree bt =  new BinaryTree() ;     //object of class
        bt.createBinaryTree();              //creating the binary tree within that object 
        Boolean b = bt.containsNode(7); 
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println("\nInorder traversal of binary tree is " );
        bt.printInorder();
    }
}
```

Comment: It’s because `createBinaryTree` doesn’t add nodes to the object it is called on. It creates a new `BinaryTree`, adds data to _that_ and then discards it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues:

- In `addrecursive` the variable `n` is a local reference that is unrelated to your `root`. So whatever `n = addrecursive(n, value);` does with the `null` that you pass as argument, it doesn't do anything with the linked list that starts at `root`.

  It is actually quite simple... Your `addrecursive` function should only do:

  ```java
      public void add(int value) {
          root = addrecursive(root, value);
      }
  ```

  The assignment to `root` is only really needed when `root` was `null`, but it doesn't hurt to always make that assignment. It is however important to pass `root` as argument, as that is the lead for where to append the new node.
- `createBinaryTree` creates a new local instance of `BinaryTree` (which is already strange, since `this` already is an instance), adds nodes to it, and then just discards that local instance -- all work done for nothing. There are different ways to solves this, but I would make this method a static method, and have it **return** the `BinaryTree` instance that it populated. The caller in `main` should then take that returned tree and assign it to its own variable:

  ```
      // Static!
      private static BinaryTree createBinaryTree(){
          BinaryTree bt = new BinaryTree();
          bt.add(6);
          bt.add(4);
          bt.add(8);
          bt.add(3);
          bt.add(5);
          bt.add(7);
          bt.add(9);
          return bt; // return the work that was done
      }

      public static void main(String [] args){
          // Call static function to get the reference to the new tree
          BinaryTree bt =  createBinaryTree(); 
          Boolean b = bt.containsNode(7); 
          System.out.println(b);
          System.out.println("\nInorder traversal of binary tree is " );
          bt.printInorder();
      }
  ```

Comment: so the line " BinaryTree bt = new BinaryTree(); " creates a binary tree i should have used bt.add directly. or used the method i made createBinaryTree (); directly with a data type BinaryTree. can u suggest a resource where i can learn about these concepts . thank you for your answer

Comment: There are many ways to organise your code. I am old style, so I would advise reading good books. Here are some suggestions: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/best-books-to-learn-java-for-beginners-and-experts/